# Not enough information on company page listings to enable user to be "more interested"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The company listing displays a company name, a location, and the number of jobs as shown:

[image]

This is hardly enough information for a candidate to click into and explore.  There is one or two pieces of key information I feel is missing but critical.  It would be nice to have the market segment or company type or even a simple (max 50 characters) introduction of the company.

For example look at IEX...Maybe IEX is popular in NY..but in MI I've never heard about it.  It would be great that between the company name and the city it said something like **Financial Services / Finance Technology**.  This at least gives me some idea what this company even does:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, we're taking a look at how we can adapt the design to display more useful content, including tagline.

Comment: We've added industry and taglines in on Company page results. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Add as an answer and I'll accept as to bring closure to this issue.  Looks great.